# Variable Multiple Field Key EF Association?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a couple of tables which are related using a multiple field key, but depending on where the application is deployed, the key may be different.

For example:

```
-Customer-     -Rep-
CompanyID      CompanyID
StoreID        StoreID
RepID          RepID
CustID
```

In some deployments a Rep's Customers are identified by joining on CompanyID, StoreID, RepID. In other deployments the Rep's StoreID will be a string of blanks and then the join is on CompanyID, RepID. The Customer will still have values in StoreID.

In SQL I just put an 'OR StoreID = "  "' where we join on the StoreID fields, but I don't see how I can do that with the entity framework.

I could set up one association for each situation and then use the appropriate one, but unless I can at runtime alias the name to the appropriate association, this would make the application code a bit messy.

Edit:

It looks like I can use the MetadataWorkspace to create the necessary association on-the-fly. I will investigate this.

Edit:

This kind of problem can be solved by splitting the model to use different csdl files (where the associations are defined) depending on which behavior is required. See MerickOWA's answer and the MSDN article linked. This introduces some minor annoyances, primarily that the designer doesn't support it, so you'll be reduced to editing XML files, and also you'll have to control which csdl resource is used. The csdl is specified in the EF connection string, which by default is in the app.config. To simplify managing this string (I needed control over the database connect string anyway), I wrote a utility class to build my EF connection string. I based this class on the code I found in [Fixing the Config: Using Entity Framework in shared libraries](http://programmersunlimited.wordpress.com/2010/09/11/fixing-the-config-using-entity-framework-in-shared-libraries/).

Comment: why would deployment affect the architecture of a database? doesn't make any sense. if different customers/deployments have different logic then it should be seperate tables (or even databases). no point trying to do "conditional" referential integrity.

Comment: The application's database is fed from the client's back end system, and they sometimes have slightly different data models, so depending on where we deploy, there are some differences. The database doesn't care which way we join the tables, so it doesn't affect the database design. I could use two entity models and pick the appropriate one during app startup. Could end up being a maintenance headache though, having to duplicate changes in both models. Would be better if there was a way to control how just the association works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility you might look into is trying to split up the edmx file into its subparts the CSDL, SSDL, and MSL.

The CSDL is your entity object layout while your SSDL is your table layout and the MSL maps between the two.

Possibly you could try having one CSDL with two or more SSDL/MSL to handle databases with different column layouts.

I don't have alot of experience using this advance situation but it certainly seems possible.

Check out this article on [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/11/25/working-with-large-models-in-entity-framework-part-2.aspx)

Comment: I agree, this looks like a workable solution. However, since I've only got one place in my model where I have this kind of deployment-specific detail, I want to  avoid building two different sets of files. If I had many places where there were differences, this might be more appealing.

Comment: That's a great MSDN article, thanks. To solve this problem this way, I would create two csdl files with the two different kinds of association. During app startup I would determine which was appropriate, then specify that csdl in the connectionString parameter when instantiating the EF model. This is easier if you break up the default connect string in the app.config. I wrote a little utility class to manage the connection string for me, based on a blog post "Fixing the Config: Using Entity Framework in shared libraries". I'll post the link as an update to my question.

Comment: @DaveK Something else you could look into is Entity Framework 4 Code First CTP5 which includes a fluent api for coding (rather than XML) table mappings which might be even more flexible and manageable but its still a work in process atm.

Comment: That looks like it would make this much easier. Right now I'm loading the ssdl, csdl, and msl resources to memory, parsing with xmldocument, modifying the key on the Rep entity and the RepCustomer association, and then manually creating the StoreItemCollection(ssdl), EdmItemCollection(csdl), the StorageMappingItemCollection(which takes those two, plus the msl), creating the metadataworkspace and registering those first three with it, then creating an EntityConnection with that workspace and the DB connection, which I then pass when I create my object context. I'll post the code when it works.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with RPM1984 your going to end up with a maintenance nightmare anyway if you aren't careful - perhaps you should consider putting foreign keys on all three cols but allow StoreId to be null and then consider using inheritance in your Model to define the Entity that maps to the table - then extending that entity for Customer & Rep and including the business logic specific to each in their respective classes...

Comment: I hadn't considered a inheritance approach to this. It seems like it would work, but it might be a little counterintuitive in the code. I'd have set up something to hide the details of which type was actually being used. I'll explore further, thanks!